# Is multiple imputation required when performing an external validation of a published Cox model?

Tags: survival

I have a sample size of n=150 - I know this may not meet the required number of events and non events, but the analysis still has to be performed.
I am missing 50 sample's results. Some have no entries (4 independent variables), and some have 1 or 2.
To account for this, would multiple imputation be necessary or recommended?

Answer (score 1):

No. Or maybe yes. The "Cox model" isn't externally validated, but a Cox model may provide inputs to develop a risk model. The risk model, therefore, is what you validate externally. The risk model should also tell you how to handle missing covariate data. The problem is that if I'm an oncologist counseling my patient on risk, I can't multiply impute their missing family history with my N of 1. The model has to tell me how to handle that.